# Deployment Error: Invalid field:** in related list:RelatedAccountContactRelationList

Tags: ant, page-layout

i am trying to deploy a package, i am getting 3 errors (the picture):

[image]

all these errors seem to be caused by a field called CONTACT.FULL_NAME, is that a valid field or you have another explications for this deployement error ?

Comment: Don't know the cause of the error but suggest its better to cut and paste the error text rather than add an image so Google can add the text to its search index.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a old post, but encountered the error today while deploying. Since no one answered, I thought of replying to the post.

The reason for this error is because the environment you extracted metadata from, has allows one contact to be related to multiple accounts. Setup can be found here ->

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=shared_contacts_set_up.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Enabling this creates a new object, 'Account Contact Relationship'.The target environment where you are deploying your code, doesn't have this setting enabled.

My production has this setting enabled, but the sandbox doesn't. I am not sure why this setting did not carry forward to sandbox. Nonetheless, making this change fixed all other errors I was getting.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's correct. 
All the three errors are due to field "CONTACT.FULL_NAME".

On Contact object, there is no Standard field named "FULL_NAME",so it is giving an error.
If it is a custom field, then we need to append '__c' to the end of the field name in the package.
So the field should be : "CONTACT.FULL_NAME__c".

This might resolve the problem.

Comment: You may be right, but i have used ANT to retrieve the layouts and i did not edit the package in any way, so i did not understand how CONTACT.FULL_NAME arrived in the package. Also, FULL_NAME is not a custom field i have checked the object and i did not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if the filed is hidden for the profile, in my case this solved my issue