# Running into error Invalid field:Contact__c in related list:Foo__c.Account__c when deploying Account layout

Tags: deployment, related-list, master-detail

Custom object `Foo__c` has master-detail relationship with object `Account` through field `Account__c`.

Custom object `Foo__c` also has master-detail relationship with object `Contact` through field `Contact__c`.

Fields `Foo__c.Account__c` and `Foo__c.Contact__c` both exist in destination org and destination org is on **Summer '20 Patch 7**

I updated account layout in source org to display object `Foo__c` related list as below and deploying to destination org:

**Account-Account - Admin.layout**:

```
<relatedLists>
    <fields>NAME</fields>
    <fields>Contact__c</fields>
    <relatedList>Foo__c.Account__c</relatedList>
</relatedLists>
```

When deploying this layout using the command `sfdx force:source:deploy`, running into error:

> Invalid field:Contact__c in related list:Foo__c.Account__c

I even added fields `Foo__c.Account__c` and `Foo__c.Contact__c` to deployment package but still running into the error.

Deploying user has access to all the fields and objects involved and I double checked API names as well.

There are similar questions on this site but those issues are referring to [Activities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204442), [AccountContactRelation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154886) which have some special properties and doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: double-check the api names as well as permissions once again.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I confirm API names and permissions look correct. I double checked.

Comment: what tool are you using to deploying this ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Updated question with those details.

Comment: I suggest use workbench to isolate if this issue is due specific to force:source:deploy. If have the zip file just use the workbench deploy utility.

Comment: @javanoob Did you find a solution to this ?Thanks

Comment: @Swetha In my situation, what happened was someone changed the relationship type from Master-Detail to Lookup in destination org but in my org it was Master-Detail. I updated the relationship type to Lookup in my org and retrieved the layout and was able to push it. I suggest checking if relationship type changed.. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: @javanoob thank you for sharing this